# Deportee transiting through South Africa

Tags: transit, south-africa, deportation, zimbabwe

I was deported last year in January from South Africa (I had illegally entered South Africa). I now intend to travel to Swaziland via South Africa. Will immigration allow me to pass through South Africa or am I not allowed even to transit through the country? I hold a Zimbabwean passport (a new one).

Comment: Does your new passport have the same details (name, date of birth, place of birth) as the one you held when you were deported?

Comment: Yes it does ,just different passport number

Comment: Are you banned from entering South Africa?